# Pass Enum type value as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, enums

I know I can check whether a String is contained in a specific Enum using the concept described by pseudo code below(I know there's no `contains` method for `Enum`, that's just for my example) :

```
Enum Animal {
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Human
}

public boolean CheckAnimalValid(String name){
    return Animal.contains(name)? true : false;
}
```

But in previous way I need to implement the ***CheckValid*** method for **each Enum** class, since I need to know **WHICH** Enum class should I to check.

I want to know is there any method to pass **Enum type** as a parameter to a function, so that I can do in this way:

```
Enum Animal {
        Dog,
        Cat,
        Person
    }

Enum Plant {
    Grass,
    Flower,
    Tree
}

public boolean CheckEnumValid(String name, what_should_I_do? enum){
    return enum.contains(name)? true : false;
}
```

I want to know which type(or keyword) should I use in **what_should_I_do?** in the previous code. I know I should use Generics, but I don't know how to do. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't write it at all. I would just use `Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` directly. NB There is no `contains()` method in an `Enum`, unless you put it there yourself.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your advice. You're right, `valueOf()` could achieve almost what I need; but I still want to know how to achieve that using generics. I tried `public <E extends Enum<E>>`, it could be compiled, however I don't know how to invoke the function. I can't use `CheckValid("test", Plant);` or  `CheckValid("test", Plant.class);`.

Comment: `Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` *already* achieves it with generics. You don't need anything else.

Comment: @EJP I know there's no `contains()` method in `Enum`, that's just for my example. The question mentioned in my last comment is that I don't know how to **invoke** that function.

Comment: See @Kapep's answer. My initial now-deleted comment was not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the static method [`Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) which returns an enum of type `T`, if the name matches an enum constants of that type. Otherwise is throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Example usage:

```
Enum.valueOf(Plant.class, "Flower");
```

Wrapped in a method that returns a boolean:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> boolean checkValid(Class<T> enumType, String name){
    try {
        Enum.valueOf(enumType, name);
        return true;
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Plant.class` should be `enumType`, and `enumType` shoulld really be `Class<E extends Enum<E>>`, for a bit more type-safety.

Comment: @Kapep Thanks! I've tried your method, and that is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if I fully understand your need but I suspect you want to lookuup in **any** `enum` by `String` - if that is the case then there are several ways to do this.

First - let's define what you are looking for - something like this?

```
interface Lookup<S,T> {
    T lookup(S s);
}
```

Now you *could* adjust every `enum` to do something like this:

```
enum Animal implements Lookup<String,Animal>{
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Person;
    Map<String,Animal> lookup = Arrays.stream(Animal.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.name(), e -> e));
    public Animal lookup(String name) {
        return lookup.get(name);
    }
}
```

But I suspect you want to do this without hacking **all** of your `enums` - which would be a pain. Here's one method using a helper object.

```
class EnumLookup<E extends Enum<E>> implements Lookup<String,E> {
    final Map<String,E> lookup;

    public EnumLookup(Class<E> clazz) {
        lookup = Arrays.stream(clazz.getEnumConstants())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.name(), e -> e));
    }

    @Override
    public E lookup(String s) {
        return lookup.get(s);
    }
}
```

Now you can create one of these to interrogate the `enum` whenever you like.

```
enum Plant {
    Grass,
    Flower,
    Tree;
}

public void test() {
    EnumLookup<Plant> lookup = new EnumLookup<>(Plant.class);
    System.out.println("Tree -> "+lookup.lookup("Tree"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you implement a generic method instead, java allows using contrains so you can for sure PASS ONLY AN ENUM, and thanks to interfaces you can restrict at compiling time what enums are allowed or not:

Define this generic method

```
public <T extends Enum<?> & ITag> void printEnum(T d) {
        System.out.println(d.name());
    }
```

define a tag interface:

```
interface ITag {
}
```

now you can **Tag** the enums that only valid in the method:

```
enum Color implements ITag {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE
}

enum STATE {
    ON, OFF
}

enum CONNECTION {
    UDP, TCP
}
```

as result, you can check if a method is taking the correct param at compiling time...

```
 printEnum(Color.GREEN); //valid
 printEnum(STATE.OFF);// invalid The method printEnum(T)... is not applicable for the arguments..
 printEnum(CONNECTION.UDP);// invalid The method printEnum(T)... is not applicable for the arguments..
 printEnum("Green"); // invalid The method printEnum(T)... is not applicable for the arguments..
```